# Xcode - Error when deleting Simulator

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I am trying to delete old simulators from `Window -> Devices` but I keep getting this error :

```
Error returned in reply: Connection invalid
```

[image]

Is there a fix for this ? Or can I delete them from the FileSystem?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Xcode do you have? Can you file a radar and include the output from `sudo sysdiagnose -q` and `xcrun simctl diagnose`?

You can use `xcrun simctl` from Terminal. The `list` command will show you your devices and `delete` will remove a device.